# How to understand a basic example for volume form?

Tags: integration, differential-forms, volume

Is there any basic example about how to understand the area and volume form? 
From where do we have this **volume form**?

Is there any way to relate this **volume form** with a very basic example? 
Is it possible to relate this **volume form** to the parallelepiped's volume?

Comment: I don't think volume-form is a necessary tag, as it simply is a $3-$form. It should fall under differential forms.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic and simple idea behind differential forms (at least to me) is that they provide a coordinate free approach to analysis and geometry. As a simple example, forms can be used to define integrals over curves, surfaces, and higher-dimensional manifolds in a uniform way. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) page can give you some flavour of the usefulness of forms.

**Example.** Consider the 2-form $\omega = dx \wedge dy$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are two vectors, then
$$
\begin{align*}
  \omega(v,w) = (dx \wedge dy) (v,w) &= dx(v) dy(w) - dx(w)dy(v) \\
 &= v_1 w_2 -v_2 w_1 \\
 &= \begin{vmatrix}
     v_1 & w_1  \\
     v_2 & w_2
    \end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}
$$
So $\omega(v,w)$ indeed gives the oriented 2-volume (the area) of the parallelepiped's volume in $\mathbb{R}^2$. A similar calculation can be used to show that $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz(u,v,w)$ is the oriented 3-volume (or just volume) of the parallelepiped in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $u$, $v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein, a basic $3$-form is a map which is defined by
$$ dx^i\wedge dx^j\wedge dx^k(u,v,w) =
\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
d x^i(u) & d x^i(v) & d^i(w) \\ 
\\
d x^j(u) & d x^j(v) & d^j(w) \\ 
\\
d x^k(u) & d x^k(v) & d^k(w) 
\end{array}\right).$$
This represents the volume of the projections $i,j,k$ of the
components of vectors $u,v,w$ in $\mathbb R^n$

For three vector $u,v,w$ in $\mathbb R^3$ this is the triple product $u\times v\bullet w$ classically known to give the volume span by those vectors, as Ernie060 is mentioning.